# Karma runner with Coverage - preprocessor not working on Javascript ES6 code

Tags: ecmascript-6, sapui5, karma-runner, code-coverage, karma-babel-preprocessor

I just recently started working with Karma runner in our UI5 app. Wrote some unit tests, ran them... all worked fine so far.

However, now I´ve decided to track the code coverage. To measure it, I need to run preprocessor on my source code. And this is where I stumbled upon a problems - I am currently trying to make it work and both have some kind of problems

1. npm package `karma-coverage` as a preprocessor - after installing it, I set it up in karma.conf.js like this

> ```
> preprocessors: {   
>     "webapp/helpers/**/*.js": ['coverage'],  
>     "webapp/controller/**/*.js": ['coverage'], 
> },
> ```

This works fine on `helpers` folder since it contains only one file with simple javascript. However, when it tries to process `controller` folder which has files with some ES6 code, each file fails with errors such as these

```
Unexpected token function
Unexpected token ...
```

2. As a second option, I tried to use `karma-babel-preprocessor` which should be able to handle also ES6 code. This is how my karma.conf.js file looks like

   preprocessors: {
         "webapp/helpers/**/*.js": ['babel'],
         "webapp/controller/***/.js": ['babel'],
         },

   ```
   babelPreprocessor: {
     options: {
       presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
       sourceMap: 'inline'
     } ,
     filename: function (file) {
       return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
     },
     sourceFileName: function (file) {
       return file.originalPath;
     } 
   },
   ```

However, this one is not even able to find the js file (even though the address is the same as in the case of coverage preprocesor) and returns this error.

```
 Error: failed to load 'sbn/portal/helpers/formatter.js' from .webapp/helpers/formatter.js: 404 - Not Found
  at https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:86:37
```

Does someone have an idea how I can get the coverage data while using these packages or any other ones? There is a lots of conflicting info on the web, most of it several years old while various karma-related npm packages keep popping up each month so I am really not sure which one would be the best to use.

Thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem and we managed to fix it integrating babel in a ui5-building-tool step.

This is how our package.json looks like:

```
 {
        "devDependencies": {
            "babel-core": "6.26.3",
            "babel-plugin-fast-async": "6.1.2",
            "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
            "karma": "^4.0.1",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
            "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
            "karma-ui5": "^1.0.0",
            "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
            "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
            "start-server-and-test": "^1.4.1",
            "@ui5/cli": "^1.5.5",
            "@ui5/logger": "^1.0.0",
        }
        "scripts": {
            "start": "ui5 serve -o index.html",
            "lint": "eslint webapp",
            "test": "karma start",
            "build": "npm run test && rimraf dist && ui5 build --a --include-task=generateManifestBundle"
      }
    }
```

This is how the ui5.yaml is looking like

```
specVersion: '1.0'
metadata:
  name: app-name
type: application
builder:
    customTasks:
    - name: transpile
      afterTask: replaceVersion
---
specVersion: "1.0"
kind: extension
type: task
metadata:
    name: transpile
task:
    path: lib/transpile.js
```

This is how the transpile.js is looking like:

Be aware that this file should be placed in the root-dir/lib folder. root-dir is the folder where ui5.yaml is residing.

```
const path = require("path");
const babel = require("babel-core");
const log = require("@ui5/logger").getLogger("builder:customtask:transpile");

/**
 * Task to transpiles ES6 code into ES5 code.
 *
 * @param {Object} parameters Parameters
 * @param {DuplexCollection} parameters.workspace DuplexCollection to read and write files
 * @param {AbstractReader} parameters.dependencies Reader or Collection to read dependency files
 * @param {Object} parameters.options Options
 * @param {string} parameters.options.projectName Project name
 * @param {string} [parameters.options.configuration] Task configuration if given in ui5.yaml
 * @returns {Promise<undefined>} Promise resolving with undefined once data has been written
 */
module.exports = function ({
    workspace,
    dependencies,
    options
}) {
    return workspace.byGlob("/**/*.js").then((resources) => {
        return Promise.all(resources.map((resource) => {
            return resource.getString().then((value) => {
                log.info("Transpiling file " + resource.getPath());
                return babel.transform(value, {
                    sourceMap: false,
                    presets: [
                        [
                            "env",
                            {
                                exclude: ["babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator", "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator"]
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        [
                            "fast-async",
                            {
                                spec: true,
                                compiler: {
                                    "promises": true,
                                    "generators": false
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                });
            }).then((result) => {
                resource.setString(result.code);
                workspace.write(resource);
            });
        }));
    });
};
```

And finally this is the karma.conf.js setup:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var ui5ResourcePath = "https:" + "//sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/";
    config.set({

        // the time that karma waits for a response form the browser before closing it
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,

        frameworks: ["ui5"],

        // list of files / patterns to exclude
        exclude: [],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
           "root_to_to_files/**/*.js": ["coverage"],
        },

        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: "dots", "progress"
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reportery
        reporters: ["progress", "coverage"],

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN ||    config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,

        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ["Chrome"],

        // Continuous Integration modey
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: true,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultaneous
        concurrency: Infinity,

        // generates the coverage report
        coverageReporter: {
            type: "lcov", // the type of the coverage report 
            dir: "reports", // the path to the output directory where the coverage report is saved
            subdir: "./coverage" // the name of the subdirectory in which the coverage report is saved
        },

        browserConsoleLogOptions: {
            level: "error"
        }


    });
};
```

In our project this setup works fine with ES6 code and prints the coverage.

Hope this you help you. Please give me a feedback how this works.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. We havent been able to make it running yet cos we dont build ui5 in the beginning but it gave us some ideas.

Comment: OK, update - in the end, we added that ui-building-tool step and used your source code. Everything works, the source codes are not only correctly transpiled but also minified. Thanks a lot!